# Wordpress frontend page with form

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress as user for while now, never came to develop anything in it.

Now I want to develop a page in frontend, where I would like to have following.

- Form with following content

  [VALUE1]

  [VALUE2]

  [VALUE3]
  SUBMIT
- Process the form values the return results.

Any helping links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a backend service to process the results. Either write a WordPress plugin. [Write Plugins (wp codex)](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin&ved=2ahUKEwj2p8b76ujYAhUsIMAKHWTVCSEQFjAAegQIEhAB&usg=AOvVaw2wnOpgH7pQ6BVUtYAw__IP)

Or if you just want to save the data or send it I suggest Contact Form 7

Comment: I want to receive values from form, then calculate it based of php logic and return the result under the form same on same page.